# What templating languages are suitable for JS and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, templates, mustache

I'm looking for a templating "language" that works for both PHP and JS. I had a look at [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) (has a very limited "if") and a few other like [jquery-tmpl-php](https://github.com/xyu/jquery-tmpl-php). So far but none of these seem to fulfil all my criteria:

- Works with data provided by JSON (array, map, literal)
- Has an "if" statement that can at least check if

  - a key in a map exists
  - a list element is first/last/odd/even
  - a value is equal to a literal
- Can iterate over a list (iterating over keys in a map would be a bonus)
- The same template and data generates exactly the same result with PHP and JS
- Fast enough (I know, it's a bit vague)
- Preferably no compiling step
- Bonus: a nice way to "pluralize" texts and basically everything that makes i18n easier
- Not smarty :)

I appreciate any ideas, suggestions or tips

Thanks,
Marek

Comment: Why using a "template" "language" at all? `var xy=<?php echo $xy; ?>;`

Comment: I'm looking for something that works with both PHP _and_ JS.

Comment: yes, I'm too. PHP _works_ with JS and it _is_ PHP ;) remember, that everything a template "thing" does is generating text, which works fine for _every_ scripting language

Comment: Could you explain this a little further? How would your example from above work under JS? I don't want to pre-render the template on the server side for different reasons.

Comment: Oh, you want a template engine _IN_ JS?! Don't know, what it should be good for, but of course you need something, that is _written_ in JS.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote this whole post up only to re-read your question and see "not Smarty" :P . I'll just say I looked around for a while for a JS and PHP template library and Smarty seemed like the best option for me. You say Mustache is not enough. The only other one that comes to mind with both JS and PHP functionality is [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/).

Original:
I don't have a ton of experience with this yet but I've started using Smarty PHP templates. I create one Smarty template and send JSON to the client for Ajax requests. I then use [this](http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/wiki/Smarty_template_in_javascript) JS Smarty engine for client-side processing. If the client does not support Javascript, I can gracefully degrade by just sending the PHP associated array to the Smarty renderer server-side rather than sending it to the JSON parser. Still uses same .smarty file, working fairly well so far and I think I'm going to keep using this methodology for the rest of my project.

Comment: Thanks, Haml look interesting. Haven't heard of it before, so I'm going to look into it.